# Can Latex automatically break words at a certain special character (underscore) in the whole document?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, babel, hyphenation

I have a large document that includes many tables like this one. I would like the filenames to break in several lines so that they fit in the column.

Is there a way to tell Latex it can break all words at a certain character, `_` in this case? (preferably without introducing a hyphen)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{.12\textwidth}|l|p{.12\textwidth}|l|l}
\hline
Filename & Balanceo & Clase mayoritaria & Result & test \\ \hline
fase\_1\_y\_2\_data.csv & Sin balanceo & 84 & 84.9 & 85.0 \\ \hline
fase\_1\_y\_3\_data.csv & Upsample & 50 en train y 84 en test bla bla bla bla & 80.1 & 72.7 \\ \hline
fase\_8\_y\_2\_data.csv & Downsample & 50 en train y 84 en test & 50.2 & 84.9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with first paragraph column that overflows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a `\url` macro that breaks on `/`, `.`, and `_` (note: use a literal `_` in the argument, not `\_`).

I also set the 3rd column ragged right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\catcode`_=12 
\newcommand{\url}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\penalty0 }%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\penalty0 }%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{_\penalty0 }%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`.=\active\catcode`_=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\catcode`_=8 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{.12\textwidth}|l|>{\raggedright}p{.12\textwidth}|l|l}
\hline
Filename & Balanceo & Clase mayoritaria & Result & test \\ \hline
\url{fase_1_y_2_data.csv} & Sin balanceo & 84 & 84.9 & 85.0 \\ \hline
\url{fase_1_y_3_data.csv} & Upsample & 50 en train y 84 en test bla bla bla bla & 80.1 & 72.7 \\ \hline
\url{fase_8_y_2_data.csv} & Downsample & 50 en train y 84 en test & 50.2 & 84.9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the `array` and `xurl` packages and encase the filenames in `\url` statements. That way, you don't have to escape underscore characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for heftier underscore characters
\usepackage{array,xurl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{.16\textwidth}|l|
                >{\raggedright}p{.24\textwidth}|l|l}
\hline
Filename & Balanceo & Clase mayoritaria & Result & test \\ \hline
\url{fase_1_y_2_data.csv} & Sin balanceo & 84 & 84.9 & 85.0 \\ \hline
\url{fase_1_y_3_data.csv} & Upsample & 50 en train y 84 en test bla bla bla bla & 80.1 & 72.7 \\ \hline
\url{fase_8_y_2_data.csv} & Downsample & 50 en train y 84 en test & 50.2 & 84.9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution that used the `\url` command from the `url` package. If you also use the `hyperref` package, you might want to surround your `tabular` with the `NoHyper` package in order to prevent hyperlinks from being created for each url. I have also added an new left aligned column type instead of the originally justified `p` type column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for the new column type
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}} 
\usepackage{url}\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{NoHyper} % only include that if you also use the hyperref package
\begin{tabular}{L{0.12}|l|L{0.12}|l|l}
\hline
Filename & Balanceo & Clase mayoritaria & Result & test \\ \hline
\url{fase_1_y_2_data.csv} & Sin balanceo & 84 & 84.9 & 85.0 \\ \hline
\url{fase_1_y_3_data.csv} & Upsample & 50 en train y 84 en test bla bla bla bla & 80.1 & 72.7 \\ \hline
\url{fase_8_y_2_data.csv} & Downsample & 50 en train y 84 en test & 50.2 & 84.9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{NoHyper}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not exactly what I was looking for because I tried to avoid editing every line but I am using it with a regexp replace. Instead of \url, I am using \nolinkurl from the same package to avoid the link (easier for me than the block solution proposed that may be better in other context).